# Refresh rate stuck at 59 Hz in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm getting a constant flickering on my monitor which I believe is due to the refresh rate getting reset to 59 Hz.  When I go into monitor settings and change the refresh rate to 60 Hz, then close the dialog and reopen, it's reset back to 59 Hz.

My environment:

- Windows 7 Enterprise (all updated to the max)
- nVidia GeForce 8600M GT video adapter
- Dell 2208WFP ultrasharp monitor

Comment: How is it displaying 59Hz in the properties dialog? Whenever I've used the dialog with an LCD screen it always just gives the single option of 60Hz.

Comment: Advanced Settings (in Screen resolution), Monitor tab, Screen Refresh Rate has 2 options: 59 hertz, 60 hertz.  It's wack.

Comment: The concept of refresh rate in LCD monitors is not the same/relevant as traditional CRT monitors.

Comment: As Sathya says, this number isn't relevant. I see 59Hz on my 27" iMac screen in Windows 7. Check out your screen card drivers, make sure your cable is connected, and there's no interference on the wire.

Comment: Randolph, post that as an answer and I'll accept if it turns out to be the case.

Answer (score 6):

This is by design for graphics cards that support TVs.  The 59 Hz is actually 59.94 Hz.  Please see this Microsoft link on the subject - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006076.